# How to distinguish between multiple AirDrop connections?

Tags: macos, user-account, airdrop

I have iMac A, MacBook Pro B, and MacBook Pro C. I want to copy a file from A to B and C using AirDrop. The problem is that I have multiple instances of the B and C machines showing up in AirDrop. I suspect it is due to multiple users being logged in on B and C. iMac A is also listing itself (under a different user?) as a destination. The problem is that AirDrop lists only the computer name, not the user account name under its icons.

**How can I find out which *users* I will be sending the file(s) to?**

I don't want to just send to all of them and later have other employees on these company machines ask me why old AirDrop requests are popping up next time they log in. I also would rather not shut down the machines and bump everyone off, interrupting whatever they might have been working on.

For today I will probably resort to another means of copying the data, but since I use AirDrop regularly I would love to get this solved. Surprisingly Google isn't giving me relevant search results on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently experiencing this issue has well.

I will test using sudo scutil to rename computers via bash but still, AirDrop on OS X Mac relies on broadcasting the computers name instead of the iCloud name if multiple users are on the same computer which is not a good idea for a corporate environment.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. But please re-post as a comment rather than an answer.